# How to view a simple history of domains (not pages) visited in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to be able to see a simple list of sites that I've recently visited but I'm not interested in the individual pages I've viewed on that site just the domain. E.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/users

would just be listed once as

- http://stackoverflow.com

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [History 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp). It replaces the default history page and enables collapsing/expanding of domains you visited.

[image]

Description of the extension:

> History 2 overrides default history
>   page with a more user-friendly one.
>   (Tools Menu > History or Ctrl-H)

Comment: History 2 is back? Cool.

Comment: I think at the moment History 2 is no more, however there might be an alternative https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-better-history/aadbaagbanfijdnflkhepgjmhlpppbad "Chrome better history"